# Java will not allow me to declare objects under an umbrella class (polymorphism)

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I am learning about polymorphism and how an umbrella class works. I have a main method which is in the class "Child". Four other classes have been created called "Ralph, "Simon", "Piggy", and "Jack". I also have an interface that these four classes implement known as "IslandAdventures", which contains the methods trait() and action(). I get an error saying to change my objects to their respective type 
Ex: Ralph ralph = new Ralph();

Code:

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    Child ralph = new Ralph();
    Child piggy = new Piggy();
    Child jack = new Jack();
    Child simon = new Simon();
    ArrayList<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
    children.add(ralph);
    children.add(piggy);
    children.add(jack);
    children.add(simon);
    for (Child child : children)
    {
    child.trait();
    child.action();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get this error?  What is the exact message?

Comment: "Type mismatch: Cannot convert piggy to Child". This is replicated for the other objects.

Comment: It also says the methods trait and action are undefined for the type child

Comment: Are you sure you have written `extends Child` in the declaration of the four child classes? How about `implements IslandAdventures`?

Comment: The error you're getting indicates that `Piggy` does not extend `Child`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you say `Child one = new Ralph();`, you're not allowed to call the `Ralph`'s `trait()` or `action()` methods. The Child type doesn't have those methods declared!

The analogy: `Ralph` is a new Samsung TV model, but you bought it with an old remote that only works with that model of TV because they're both from Samsung (`Child`), and your remote doesn't have the required buttons to do all the functions of the TV.

You can fix this by either getting the right remote (eg: what the error says to do, change the `Child` type to `Ralph` type) or you can make it so that the remote always has those buttons (implement `IslandAdventures` in `Child`).

Edit: based on the comments under your question, I think the bigger problem here is that you haven't extended Child in your classes.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine I created a new child, Foo, that inherits from `Child`. This means that it can belong to the list `children`. However, Foo does not implement `IslandAdventures`. What happens when I get foo out of the list, and try to call `trait()` and `action()` on Foo?

Solution would be to declare an `ArrayList<IslandAdventures>` since all members implement the interface, or have `Child` implement `IslandAdventures`, so that all subclasses of `Child` *also* implement it.